# How to prevent multiple pages opening while clicking the Items in Master Detail page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Steps to reproduce the issue
1. clicking the item in details page. 
2. Page will open and 
3. again open the page and 
4. clicking the same item another item page will display on the existing item page

```
void  OnTapGestureMenuTermsAndConditionsTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    IsPresented = false;

    Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new AgreeTerms());
}
```

---

**EDIT**

First of all i given clarification on my issue

AgreeTerms() are sup-rate page and

This page, I navigate the page through masterpage(Menu page, Here I give the link to navigate "AgreeTerms" page),  While click on link "AgreeTerms" page open and again click same link page open another page(overlap previous page), The Code to navigate page in masterpage ,

```
void  OnTapGestureMenuTermsAndConditionsTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    IsPresented = false;

    Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new AgreeTerms());
}
```

and while navigate the page(AgreeTerms) , I want to close the page(AgreeTerms) again, Here I write the code , This is code in AgreeTerms page

```
private async void Deleteimg_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0 || Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(AgreeTerms))
    { 
        Navigation.PopAsync(false); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: PushAsync runs asynchronously, you might want to run it in a asynchronous method and await it

Comment: Show the declaration of `IsPresented`. Is that property refered of xaml aswell ?

Comment: I try code asynchronously , same Issue

Comment: Please post it as an Edit in your question and format it properly for a better understanding and mutual help :)

Comment: Show me your XAML aswell

Comment: Sorry . IsPresented is property of MasterDetailPage class

Comment: and Detail also property of MasterDetailPage class

Comment: I change the code, please see once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
void  OnTapGestureMenuTermsAndConditionsTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   IsPresented = false;

   if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Where(x => x is AgreeTerms).Count() > 0)
       return;
   Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new AgreeTerms());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question a little confusing, but I think that you want to prevent the same page from opening twice.

If this is the case, you could check current page's type and only Push if it's different from the type that will be pushed. Like so:

```
void  OnTapGestureMenuTermsAndConditionsTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    IsPresented = false;

    if (Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(AgreeTerms))
        Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new AgreeTerms());
}
```

Hope it helps!

---

**EDIT**

Forget about `Deleteimg_Tapped`, you can delete this method from `AgreeTerms`.

You only need to change the `OnTapGestureMenuTermsAndConditionsTapped` to the code that I posted up here.

If you change from this:

```
void  OnTapGestureMenuTermsAndConditionsTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    IsPresented = false;

    Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new AgreeTerms());
}
```

To this:

```
void  OnTapGestureMenuTermsAndConditionsTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    IsPresented = false;

    if (Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(AgreeTerms)) // Only add this line
        Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new AgreeTerms());
}
```

It will work.

Comment: I got error : ('Page' Does not a contain a definition for "Current Page" and no extension method
'Current page' accepting a firts argument of type of type 'page'coul;d be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   )

Comment: It's because the `Detail` must be a `NavigationPage`, not a `Page`

Comment: Actually, I think it's better if you make your Detail page a NavigationPage. And in your code you use `Detail.Navigation.PushAsync`, to use this method your Detail needs to be a NavigationPage anyway. Instead of declaring your `Detail` as `Detail = new YourPage()`, use `Detail = new NavigationPage(new YourPage())`. And set `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false)` in `YourPage` constructor if you don't want to have a NavigationBar.

Comment: Ok.. I try Using the code `Detial=NavigationPage(new AgreeTerms())`, i have a one more issue i.e. While i close the page(AgreeTerms),  it is not closed. (I put the close page code)  `private async void Deleteimg_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0 || Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(AgreeTerms))
            {
               
                Navigation.PopAsync(false);
            }     } `

Comment: Please Help Me, as soon as possible

Comment: First of all, I think that the OR (`||`) operator should be an AND operator (`&&`). Now, if you change that operator to AND, it makes sense that it's not popping the page, as the condition is "if the last page IS NOT an AgreeTerms, close it". As your last page IS an AgreeTerms, the PopAsync should not be called. But with this OR I can't say the error, perhaps you should debug and see if the PopAsync is getting called and `await` it (`await Navigation.PopAsync(false);`.

Comment: Ok. While i give "&&" Operator, the "IF" Condition will be False

Comment: Yes, you will have to change it from `Detail.CurrentPage.GetType() != typeof(AgreeTerms)` to `Detail.CurrentPage.GetType() == typeof(AgreeTerms))` (from **!=** to **==**) when you are doing the PopAsync (but don't change it when you are going to Push the page as you want it to only push if the current page is NOT the AgreeTerms). Got it?

Comment: as your suggestion, i give "==" Operator the "IF"condition `if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0 && Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() == typeof(AgreeTerms))` , page will not close

Comment: Are you sure PopAsync is getting called? Is AgreeTerms already at NavigationStack when you call PopAsync? Is NavigationStack.Count > 0 or you are at the Root of the Navigation?

Comment: Hi I added, Clarity on Issue, Please and help me and I am Poor in english, if u not understand any thing please ask me again

Comment: Please see 2 Answer